# Most efficient way to find the average of multiple dataframe rows with similar but changing values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter, analysis

I have a dataframe which contains data regarding CO2 levels over time and has two key columns: Year and ppm. Year goes from 1974 to 2019, and there are several rows for each year. So for example 1974 starts with a ppm of 333.34, and very next row is 1974 with a ppm of a slightly different ppm. There's 2000+ rows total. I want to get the average ppm for each year and plot for each single year.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. Right now some things I've considered:

```
df_Year = df.loc[df['Year']==1975]
```

which would isolate all of the 1975 rows, then use

```
df_Year['ppm'].astype("float").mean(axis=0)
```

and I could then get the average that way, but that's just one year. I am thinking I could make a loop which iterates through each year and gets the average and then assigns the average ppm to a list or dictionary or something.

But it just seems kind of lengthy. Isn't there a more efficient way?

Comment: did you try `df.groupby('Year')['ppm'].mean()` ?

Comment: `df.groupby('Year').ppm.mean()`

Comment: Two swift comments on the wings of coding angels. I will give that a try. Thank you!